# Expected operands to be a string or number type

Tags: angular

I have this code in angular 2:

```
 <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of vehicleHistoryList | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : page * pageSize">
            <th scope="row">{{item.plateNumber}}</th>
            <td>{{item.entryPlaza}}</td>
            <td>{{item.entryLane}}</td>
            <td>{{item.entryDtime}}</td>
            <td>{{item.exitPlaza}}</td>
            <td>{{item.exitDtime}}</td>
            <!-- 'data:image/jpg;base64,' -->
            <td>
              <img [src]="this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,' + item.img)" /> // ====> THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
            </td>
            <td>
            <button
                class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success btn-round btn-icon"
              >
                <i class="nc-icon nc-send"></i>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

This is how I get the list in the TS file

```
this.ps.getEntryImformation(model).subscribe((ret: VehicleHistory[]) => {
      this.ps.setVehicleHistory(ret);
   });
```

Why can't I render the image in my table and although, I don't have error in my console, I get an error in the text editor "Expected operands to be a string or number type
"

Comment: why you use `this.` in your template? remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6aunm9?file=src/app/app.component.ts) make it with pipe for image for securtiy u can use pipe below

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
 
 public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
  }

}
```

and show image use pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'media'
    })
    export class MediaPipe implements PipeTransform {
        constructor() {}
        public transform(img: any){
            return 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + img
        }
    }
```

in html

```
  <img [src]="(item.img | media) | safe : 'url'" />
```